# KPL vs Kinesis Aggregation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, producer-consumer

I need to a create a lambda that reads from the aggregated data from one account's Kinesis stream and inputs it into another account's Kinesis Stream.

I am new in AWS. I am researching on the ways how a lambda can be used as producer of a kinesis stream.
I am getting confused on KPL or Kinesis Aggregator.

Can anyone help on this?

https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-aggregation/blob/master/java/KinesisTestProducers/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/kinesis/producer/SampleKPLProducer.java

https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-aggregation/blob/master/java/KinesisTestProducers/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/kinesis/producer/SampleAggregatorProducer.java

Comment: I'm not sure there's a clear question here. What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: The differences of the two are explained here. https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-aggregation